# var_dump in php gives error of illegal character how to avoid it

Tags: php, var-dump

i have a small function to write contents

```
function write($data)
{
  file_put_contents("filename.txt",$data,FILE_APPEND);
}
```

it works good except some where when i do the following

```
write( var_dump($someObject) );
```

this gives an error message of

> illegal character.

I see the this error message through an alert box in browser the php gets call through an ajax call. Any help in debugging this would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: It might help to check what characters are actually contained in "filename.txt". And also posting the ajax code would be a good idea. The alert does not come by itself...

Comment: Is the file opened with the binary flag?

Comment: `var_export($someObject,true)` should be the better solution here.

Comment: Since a string is required to be written in a file, `var_export($someObject)` should do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`var_dump` will not work like that because it outputs directly instead of returning the output. If you want to capture the output in order to write it somewhere else you have to use [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php):

```
ob_start();
var_dump($data);
write(ob_get_clean());
```

Alternatively, `var_export` is also something that would work as long as you remember to pass in `true` for the second parameter:

```
write(var_export($data, true));
```

Answer (score 2):

The function `var_dump()` ([see Documentation](http://php.net/var_dump)) does echo all the content. You should use `var_export()` ([see Documentation](http://php.net/var_export)) here.

```
write(var_export($data, true));
```